# Allow user to share on Facebook anonymously: options?

Tags: facebook

I want to allow users to share memes anonymously with their friends.

I am trying to figure out how this can be done through Facebook: are there any Facebook APIs which will allow users to share through a different profile, or anonymously altogether? e.g. I create a 'anonymous' profile, the user simply inputs their meme and selects all the friends they want to share with, and all that the friends will see is that a message has been sent by 'anonymous'. Is this possible? Alternative solutions?

Comment: This would be spam. Plus, your 'annonymous' account wouldn't be friends with your users friends.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as an anonymous Facebook profile, and fake/falsified profiles are against their TOS and will be shut down. (If/Once caught, of course.) Zuckerberg–and hence Facebook to a certain extent–is squarely *against* on-line anonymity. I don't see any way their system would facilitate what you're trying. That's before we even get to the fact that it'll almost certainly *rapidly* get flagged as a spam source by recipients who suddenly start getting unwanted links from some unknown source.

Comment: +1 and related: "... [A] privacy change for 350 million users is not the kind of thing that a lot of companies would do, but we viewed that as a really important thing, to always keep a beginner's mind and what would we do if we were starting the company now and we decided that these would be the social norms now and we just went for it." - [Mark Zuckerberg says privacy is no longer a 'social norm'](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/facebook/6966628/Facebooks-Mark-Zuckerberg-says-privacy-is-no-longer-a-social-norm.html)

Comment: I am referring to, more or less, a third party application/API which will allow a Facebook user to essentially send a meme to all his/her friends by proxying through another 'user' profile (thus effectively remaining anonymous in the transaction). I am not talking about direct cloaking.